# Facial Recognition - Changing the recognition points

Tags: iphone, ios, face-recognition

I'm having trouble with this. I'm trying to change the two eye points in facial recognition to be a pair of sunglasses.

I'm new to this site so please forgive me for inaccurately posting if I have.

this is the output I currently am getting. https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEtzK.png

```
{
// draw a CI image with the previously loaded face detection picture
CIImage* image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:facePicture.image.CGImage];

// create a face detector - since speed is not an issue we'll use a high accuracy
// detector
CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace 
                                          context:nil options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy]];

// create an array containing all the detected faces from the detector    
NSArray* features = [detector featuresInImage:image];

// we'll iterate through every detected face.  CIFaceFeature provides us
// with the width for the entire face, and the coordinates of each eye
// and the mouth if detected.  Also provided are BOOL's for the eye's and
// mouth so we can check if they already exist.
for(CIFaceFeature* faceFeature in features)
{
    // get the width of the face
    CGFloat faceWidth = faceFeature.bounds.size.width;

    // create a UIView using the bounds of the face
    UIView* faceView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:faceFeature.bounds];

    // add a border around the newly created UIView
    faceView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    faceView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];

    // add the new view to create a box around the face
    [self.window addSubview:faceView];

    if(faceFeature.hasLeftEyePosition)
    {
        // create a UIView with a size based on the width of the face
        UIView* leftEyeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(faceFeature.leftEyePosition.x-faceWidth*0.15, faceFeature.leftEyePosition.y-faceWidth*0.15, faceWidth*0.3, faceWidth*0.3)];
        // change the background color of the eye view
        [leftEyeView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3]];
        // set the position of the leftEyeView based on the face
        [leftEyeView setCenter:faceFeature.leftEyePosition];
        // round the corners
        leftEyeView.layer.cornerRadius = faceWidth*0.15;
        // add the view to the window
        [self.window addSubview:leftEyeView];
    }

    if(faceFeature.hasRightEyePosition)
    {
        // create a UIView with a size based on the width of the face
        UIView* leftEye = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(faceFeature.rightEyePosition.x-faceWidth*0.15, faceFeature.rightEyePosition.y-faceWidth*0.15, faceWidth*0.3, faceWidth*0.3)];
        // change the background color of the eye view
        [leftEye setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3]];
        // set the position of the rightEyeView based on the face
        [leftEye setCenter:faceFeature.rightEyePosition];
        // round the corners
        leftEye.layer.cornerRadius = faceWidth*0.15;
        // add the new view to the window
        [self.window addSubview:leftEye];
    }

    if(faceFeature.hasMouthPosition)
    {
        // create a UIView with a size based on the width of the face
        UIView* mouth = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(faceFeature.mouthPosition.x-faceWidth*0.2, faceFeature.mouthPosition.y-faceWidth*0.2, faceWidth*0.4, faceWidth*0.4)];
        // change the background color for the mouth to green
        [mouth setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3]];
        // set the position of the mouthView based on the face
        [mouth setCenter:faceFeature.mouthPosition];
        // round the corners
        mouth.layer.cornerRadius = faceWidth*0.2;
        // add the new view to the window
        [self.window addSubview:mouth];
    }
}

-(void)faceDetector
{
    // Load the picture for face detection
    UIImageView* image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facedetectionpic.jpg"]];

    // Draw the face detection image
    [self.window addSubview:image];

    // Execute the method used to markFaces in background
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(markFaces:) withObject:image];

    // flip image on y-axis to match coordinate system used by core image
    [image setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)];

    // flip the entire window to make everything right side up
    [self.window setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)];
}
```

Comment: What's your problem, it looks quite good in the image.

Comment: Thanks :) But I was curious how to add an image to replace the dots that show over the eyes. So I wanted to be able to substitute the dots for an image. I have googled and googled but just can't find how to do it.